# Find noninvertible $T:P(\mathbb R) \rightarrow P(\mathbb R)$ and $S:P(\mathbb R) \rightarrow P(\mathbb R)$ such that $TS=I_{P(\mathbb R)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $P(\mathbb R)$ be the vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients. Find noninvertible $T:P(\mathbb R) \rightarrow P(\mathbb R)$ and $S:P(\mathbb R) \rightarrow P(\mathbb R)$ such that $TS=I_{P(\mathbb R)}$

I think this is one of those problems where once you find an answer, it clicks, but I can't think of any that are able to do this. Every function I think of is invertible, which they can't be.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**: As the identity is invertible, you know that $S$ has to be injective, and $T$ has to be surjective (prove this if it's not obvious to you). Now you just need to find an example of, say $S$ which is injective but not surjective. Can you then find an example of a $T$ so that they compose to give the identity?

**Hint 2**: Although you don't need to use this hint, it may spark an idea for you. Recall the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of something where for polynomial $a_n x^n+...+a_1x+a_0$, we could just make it $a_{n}x^{n+1}...a_1x^2+a_0x$. Then this, $S$, isn't surjective because we can't map to any constant, but it is injective, I think.  Then I could just have $T$ be the reverse.  Does something like that work or am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: That's exactly right! Just make sure when writing it down that you are careful to show why each has the desired properties. My second hint was pointing to $S$ being integration and $T$ being differentiation, but yours works just as well and, if anything, is more simple.